# How to upload a torrent file programmatically

Tags: file-upload, uploadify, bittorrent

We have a client with an upload site we built (using Ruby/RoR) and he wants to add the ability to upload files from a torrent link.

Right now you can upload files from a PC or URL.. what is the best way to programmatically upload a file from a torrent link?

It seems that we would need to first upload the torrent in a tmp directory, then extract the file.. and move that file to the uploaded directory..

I appreciate input from anyone with experience in this (in any programming lang.)

Feature:
  In order to upload a file from a torrent link
  As a registered user of the site
  I want to be able to paste the URL of a torrent file
  Then have that file uploaded to the website, not the torrent file itself.

Comment: Thank you Robert.. I will go back and do that.. I tried initially, but the site said I needed to wait until I had a rep higher than 15.. so I could not do so during the initial Q&A ;) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Robert.. I've revisited my previous questions, voted and selected the accept solution. Thanks again.

Comment: anyone have an idea of how to provide a URL to an app, and have that app upload the file assoc with the torrent ???

Comment: Hello Robert... I was checking back to see if there is any feedback you can offer on this issue? We're still dealing with it and have not been able to find a feasible solution..

Comment: you must keep the torrent file untill the orginal file is done downloading. Then you can use maketorrent to create a new torrentfile by command line and store it where ever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Given a torrent file or magnet link, it's possible to obtain the file list for the torrent. The uploader could then specify which files in the torrent to upload. The server side can download the specified files in the torrent using bittorrent.

A link to a torrent file is as good as the torrent file itself, assuming the server can fetch from that address.